# at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:84)

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I use the eclipse debug hadoop, there is an error, how to solve this problem

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
        log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:404)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:435)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:277)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:125)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:344)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1286)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:84)
```

Comment: Can you write the command you used?

Comment: The file system is pointing to LocalFileSystem. Check whether **fs.default.name** property is configured in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running your code on `/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20` and not on `/usr/lib/hadoop/client`.

My error was solved by following this step.